# I am unable to display my corresponding region for the largest PSI value

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, max

I am unable to display my corresponding region among all regions for the highest PSI reading.

I have tried many other various methods, but I could not display my corresponding region (Central, East, North, South, West....) for that highest PSI value.

I have declared the PSI values in the arrays for each region.

```
int i, largest;

int Time[] = { 600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800 };
int Central[] = { 89,88,87,143,139,79,144,85,83,90,89,88,76 };
int East[] = { 80,79,78,77,76,80,90,89,88,110,109,143,136 };
int North[] = { 147,144,141,139,137,132,109,110,109,80,77,132,108 };
int South[] = { 90,89,88,139,136,132,102,105,109,110,109,80,77 };
int West[] = { 141,137,153,147,143,83,90,89,141,138,134,130,127 };

largest = Central[0];
for (i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (largest < Central[i])
        largest = Central[i];
}
largest = Central;

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (largest < East[i])
        largest = East[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (largest < North[i])
        largest = North[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (largest < South[i])
        largest = South[i];
}
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    if (largest < West[i])
        largest = West[i];
}
printf(" Highest PSI value amongst all is %d\n\n\n", largest); 
break;
```

I am able to display my largest PSI value, but I am not able to display the region for that highest PSI value.

For example, if my largest PSI in the arrays was 180 that is in Central, it will display PSI value is 180 and correspondent region is Central.

If my largest PSI in the arrays was 180 that is in West, it will display PSI value is 180 and correspondent region is West.

Comment: This statement largest = Central; does not make sense. Remove it.

Comment: Apart from that, the code finds the largest value `153` (there isn't a `180` value). The `break;` should be removed too.

Comment: Am I the only one wondering what "PSI" means?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar It is not important.:)

Comment: *I am not able to display the region*. Add another variable `int region`, and every time you set `largest` also set that variable to `0`, `1` etc so you know which region had the largest PSI.

Answer (score 0):

1. You assign an array to an int : `largest = Central;`
2. You need to create a variable containing the name of the region and update it each time the PSI is larger. All you have to do is print it at the end. Which give us :

```c
    #include <stdio.h>

    int i, largest;
    char *region = NULL;

    int Time[] = { 600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800 };
    int Central[] = { 89,88,87,143,139,79,144,85,83,90,89,88,76 };
    int East[] = { 80,79,78,77,76,80,90,89,88,110,109,143,136 };
    int North[] = { 147,144,141,139,137,132,109,110,109,80,77,132,108 };
    int South[] = { 90,89,88,139,136,132,102,105,109,110,109,80,77 };
    int West[] = { 141,137,153,147,143,83,90,89,141,138,134,130,127 };


    largest = Central[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        if (largest < Central[i]) {
            largest = Central[i];
            region = "Central";
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (largest < East[i]) {
            largest = East[i];
            region = "East";
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (largest < North[i]) {
            largest = North[i];
            region = "North";
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (largest < South[i]) {
            largest = South[i];
            region = "South";
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (largest < West[i]) {
            largest = West[i];
            region = "West";
        }
    }
    printf(" Highest PSI value amongst all is %d in %s\n\n\n", largest, region);
```

Comment: You changed the initialisation of `largest` but not the loop starting value, which should be `for(i = 0; ...)` . Also it should be initialised `largest = INT_MIN;` so as not to make any presumptions about the data.

Comment: `largest = -1;` This will fail if the arrays contain negative values.Also: If you want to improve code, combine alle the `for` loop to one loop.

Comment: I'm just solving his problem to display the region, I'm not improving his code, it wasn't my goal.

Comment: Yeah but you *changed the code* so now it doesn't work when `Central[0]` is the largest.

Comment: Oh ! I forgot to change the start value of the first loop

Comment: If `Central[0]` largest, it won't assign `Central` to `region`.

Answer (score 0):

To find largest region's name, create another variable to store which region has the largest value and assign it inside each `if` statement.

Also, I've combined your `for` loops to make your code clearer.

```
int i, largest;
char region[strlen("Central") + 1];

int Time[] = { 600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800 };
int Central[] = { 89,88,87,143,139,79,144,85,83,90,89,88,76 };
int East[] = { 80,79,78,77,76,80,90,89,88,110,109,143,136 };
int North[] = { 147,144,141,139,137,132,109,110,109,80,77,132,108 };
int South[] = { 90,89,88,139,136,132,102,105,109,110,109,80,77 };
int West[] = { 141,137,153,147,143,83,90,89,141,138,134,130,127 };

largest = Central[0]; 

// Combine the for loops to make your code more clear
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) 
{
    if (largest < Central[i]){
        largest = Central[i];
        region = "Central";
    }
    if (largest < East[i]){
        largest = East[i];
        region = "East";
    }
    if (largest < North[i]){
        largest = North[i];
        region = "North";
    }
    if (largest < South[i]){
        largest = South[i];
        region = "South";
    }
    if (largest < West[i]){
        largest = West[i];
        region = "West";
    }
}

// Display results
printf("PSI value is %d and correspondent region is %s.", largest, region);
```

Comment: `largest = 0;` There is no statement that excludes negative values from the array. Using `largest = 0;` was actually correct. But `region` also needs proper initialization.

Comment: I believe I fixed it.

Comment: No, you still assign `0` as start value. There is no need to allocate memory for `region`. Just assign string literals.

Answer (score 0):

This statement in your code snippet

```
largest = Central;
```

is redundant and does not make sense (it tries convert a pointer to int).

It seems what you mean is something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 13 };        
    int Central[N] = { 89,88,87,143,139,79,144,85,83,90,89,88,76 };
    int East[N]    = { 80,79,78,77,76,80,90,89,88,110,109,143,136 };
    int North[N]   = { 147,144,141,139,137,132,109,110,109,80,77,132,108 };
    int South[N]   = { 90,89,88,139,136,132,102,105,109,110,109,80,77 };
    int West[N]    = { 141,137,153,147,143,83,90,89,141,138,134,130,127 };

    const int *regions[] = { Central, East, North, South, West };

    const char *region_name[] = { "Central", "East", "North", "South", "West" };

    int largest_PSI = regions[0][0];
    const char *target_region_name = region_name[0];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( regions ) / sizeof( *regions ); i++ )
    {
        int region_largest_PSI = regions[i][0];
        for ( size_t j = 1; j < N; j++ )
        {
            if ( region_largest_PSI < regions[i][j] )
            {
                region_largest_PSI = regions[i][j];
            }
        }

        if ( largest_PSI < region_largest_PSI )
        {
            largest_PSI = region_largest_PSI;               
            target_region_name = region_name[i];
        }
    }

    printf( "Highest PSI value amongst all is %d in region %s.\n\n\n", largest_PSI, target_region_name );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Highest PSI value amongst all is 153 in region West.
```

To simplify the code you could write a separate function that searches the maximum element. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * max_element( const int a[], size_t N )
{
    const int *max = a;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( *max < *( a + i ) ) max = a + i; 
    }

    return ( int * )max;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 13 };        
    int Central[N] = { 89,88,87,143,139,79,144,85,83,90,89,88,76 };
    int East[N]    = { 80,79,78,77,76,80,90,89,88,110,109,143,136 };
    int North[N]   = { 147,144,141,139,137,132,109,110,109,80,77,132,108 };
    int South[N]   = { 90,89,88,139,136,132,102,105,109,110,109,80,77 };
    int West[N]    = { 141,137,153,147,143,83,90,89,141,138,134,130,127 };

    const int * regions[] = { Central, East, North, South, West };

    const char *region_name[] = { "Central", "East", "North", "South", "West" };

    int largest_PSI = regions[0][0];
    const char *target_region_name = region_name[0];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( regions ) / sizeof( *regions ); i++ )
    {
        int *region_largest_PSI = max_element( regions[i], N );

        if ( largest_PSI < *region_largest_PSI )
        {
            largest_PSI = *region_largest_PSI;              
            target_region_name = region_name[i];
        }
    }

    printf( "Highest PSI value amongst all is %d in region %s.\n\n\n", largest_PSI, target_region_name );

    return 0;
}
```